# Pagination with "data display limit" per page using UITableView

Tags: ios, json, swift, uitableview, pagination

I have some `data` coming from an `API`, in the following structure:

```
{
    "AssetType": "Watch",
    "checkDate": "2020-08-22",
    "totalCount": 31,
    "hasMore": true,
    "skip": 10,
    "items": [
        {
            "id": "150",
            "name": "Rolex",
            "includeExtraParts": 0,
            "package": "box",
            "unit": "g",
            "manufacture": null,
            "totalPrice": 1738.04310497
        },
       ... ..
    ]
}
```

I have parsed and displayed the data in my `UITableView` so far, and I want to fetch more data while `hasMore` flag is `true` and want to display the `data` of 10 counts per `fetch` in my `UITableView` till the `hasMore` flag becomes `false`..

However, I can only `fetch` and display 10 counts of parsed data inside my `UITableView`..
How can I properly implement the `data pagination` in order to achieve what I am trying to accomplish?

here is what I have tried so far and it is NOT working properly and NOT invoking the `pagination` effect at all:

Inside `viewDidLoad()`:

```
 ApiCaller.getData(token: token, dataID: dataID, skip: skip, completion: { (response) in
    self.total = response.totalCount
    self.hasMore = response.hasMore
    self.skip = response.skip
    if self.skip < response.totalCount && response.hasMore == true {
        self.data = response.items
        
    }  else {
        return
    }
    self.tableVIew.reloadData()
})
```

and my `func loadMore()` logic:

```
  func loadMore() {
        if (self.hasMore == false) {
            return
        } else {
            DispatchQueue.main.asyncAfter(deadline: .now() + 1) {
                //calls the Api caller func inside viewDidLoad()
                self.getData()
            }
            
        }
    }
```

and finally, inside `UITableViewDelegate`, I did/ called it like this:

```
    func tableView(_ tableView: UITableView, willDisplay cell: UITableViewCell, forRowAt indexPath: IndexPath) {
        
        if (self.hasMore == false) || (self.data.count == 0) {
            return
        }
        
        if indexPath.row == self.data.count - 3 {
            loadMore()
        }        
    }
```

and it is not working. Can anyone help me through this logic, please?

Comment: reload tableview on main ui thread

Comment: also does not need -3, -1 is okay.

Comment: you load more function need to just check hasmore property instead fetching data from server

Answer (score 0):

As it seems you are overriding your self.data property each time you are getting new data. I am assuming this property is an array. If it is use [.append(contentsOf:)](https://developer.apple.com/documentation/swift/array/3126939-append) method to add the newly fetched data to the already fetched one.

```
if self.skip < response.totalCount && response.hasMore == true {
   self.data = response.items // You are overriding your data each time here       
 }
```